# How to get Google-Calendar events using access token

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I have built a django app, which it includes google Oauth2.0 login.
I want to get google calendar events of every users when they login with Oauth2.0 and I wrote the following code. I saved the access token into UserAuth table and fetched it, then used it to get google calendar.

```
def get_events_server(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    creds = UserAuth.objects.get(user=user).google_id_token

    credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(creds, "")
    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', http=http)
    return service
```

When I run the code, the following error has happened.

```
HttpError at /calendar/
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?timeMin=2021-10-28T04%3A33%3A08.956703Z&timeMax=2021-11-04T04%3A33%3A08.956712Z&singleEvents=true&timeZone=GMT%2B9%3A00&orderBy=startTime&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
```

Is there a solution to skip this issue?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how you got the access tokens? For getting them, did users authenticate as themselves? If you got it by authenticating as your account, the access token will only have access to the events your account can access.

Comment: yes, Users will login with their google account like Oauth login, they will take their access token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a little confused here lets start by looking at the difference between authentication and authorization.

Authentication or Open Id connect is signin your letting a user signin to their google account and you get an id token back and you are able to access their profile information because the user signed in.  You are authentication that the user who is behind the machine owns the account.  In your code see the id_token you are using Open id connect to authentication the user.

```
creds = UserAuth.objects.get(user=user).google_id_token
```

In order to access a users private data your application needs to be authorized to access that data.  Authorization is defined by scopes, or the scope of access you need.  In order to use the google calendar api you will need an access token with a scope that will give you permission to access the users google calendar events

You should have a look at the [Python quickstart for google calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python) it will show you how to use Oauth2 to have your application request authorization from the user to access their google calendar data.

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])
```

## from comments

Your link consent screen request is returning an error. This is the redirect uri miss match errror and its one of the most common Errors you can get when you are setting up oauth2.

[image]

If you check the error it is telling you that there is an issue with this url `redirect_uri: http://localhost:61668/`  you are sending your request from that url. which means you need to go to google cloud console and add that redirect uri to your list of accepted redirect uris.  Remember it must match exactly so the port number and trailing slash must be included.

These are your current redirect uris you need to add `http://localhost:61668/`

[image]

try setting

```
flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

to

```
flow.run_local_server(port=8000)
```

then add

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

as your redirect uri.

If you don't know how this Video will show you how to fix it. [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ&t=7s)

Comment: I am not sure where I should get the token.json and credentials.json? this files are information of my access token or user's token? @DaimTo

Comment: [credentials.json](https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ) is created in your project when you register it on Google Developer console. Just remember under library to enable the Google Calendar api.    token.json is created when the user runs our application for the first time their credentials refresh token and access token will be stored in that file.  I suggest you follow the quickstart it explains how to create them.

Comment: I just followed your code and run it, in that case the following errors: Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=780686333688-51gn25ap4hk2q6pvksir6dsvj1tfs1a6.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61668%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar&state=k6JKUFbK2oJjUf9L0nXfKBjHgxfT2E&access_type=offline

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: I added the redirect_uri but it takes same error. @DalmTo

Comment: Edit your question and include a screen shot of what you have included in google cloud console.  Your redirect uri is still wrong.   Side note: remember if your app is in production you cant use HTTPS or localhost.

Comment: My app is in Test

Comment: Looks to me like you only have http://localhost:8000/calendar/ and  http://localhost:8000/login/ added you still need to add http: //localhost:61668/ Did you watch the video i linked it walks you though what the redirect uri is and how to add a new one.

Comment: The port is changed continually, localhost:61668 is not Unchanging. for example localhost:54234, localhost:51884, localhost:81002 and so on.
This is coming from flow.run_local_server(port=0)

Comment: You need to fix your IDE so that it does not change the port you need your application to run on a static port.   Set to run on a  default_port  check edit.

Comment: flow.run_local_server(port=8000), this command takes error  because the port:8000 is running already. as you know django default port is just 8000

Comment: Pick a different one :) they key is your system needs to run on a stack port and you need to add properly

Comment: @DaImTo I wanted to ask does `flow.run_local_server(port=0)` works after hosting on website and What changes are required after hosting website ?